# i'm using python 3.7.7 but i have a problem while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm new at python (version of python 3.7.7) and I'm trying to run a finished project, I imported everything but tensorflow is not working the error is shown down below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL)
initialization routine failed. During handling of the above exception,
another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/User/Desktop/adsp/train.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util   File
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py",
line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL)
initialization routine failed. Failed to load the native TensorFlow
runtime. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common
reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this
error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you trying to install ?

Comment: I installed tensorflow version 2.4.0

Comment: "See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions." -- What did you find? Did it help? Did you check the bugtracker?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is of compatibility. The version of tensorflow which you are trying to run with python 3.7 is not compatible with the same. In order to check for possible compatible versions please visit this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

Also in case you are facing too many issues while trying to install some library in python and your work is getting held, I'd recommend you to make use of [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#recent=true).

There you won't need to worry about installation of packages. Although one must experience the installation and setup of packages as a learning.

Comment: Hello again and thank you for your help, i tried a LOT of versions and i still get the same error i even deleted python and reinstalled it tensorflow is not working i dont know whats wrong. Now i have python 3.6.0 downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling tensorflow from pip and reinstalling it again. It seems you have an import error. Also if you have two or more Python versions on your machine, this can cause issues sometimes

Comment: first thank you for your help. I already tried to uninstall tensorflow from pip and reinstalling it again and i dont think i have two python versions since i remember that i've deleted the latest version then downgraded to 3.7.7